# Close another window in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm building a multi-window app.
The problem I've got, I can't close "Window1" or "Window2" from button in "MainWindow".
All windows are in the same app.
Is there a way to kill another window?

Comment: What @Dominik mean is that ... keep a reference to your Window1 and Window2 when you create those windows from Main. Then you can do whatever you want on them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure there is. If you have a reference to that `Window`, just call the [`Close()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.close%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

```
Window window1 = new Window1();
window1.Show();
...
window1.Close();
```

Comment: never though it would be that easy. It was launched in from another class with certain conditions but created static reference in main window. Works like a harm!